# TeamCity repeatedly downloading and updating jetbrains.git plugin

Tags: git, jetbrains-ide, teamcity-9.0

Can someone advise what could be wrong with our TeamCity (version 9), it is repeatedly downloading, updating and unzipping jetbrains.git.zip plugin in folder

`<TeamCity Program Dir>\BuildAgent\update\plugins`

[image: Performance Monitor Screenshot]

See attached performance monitor screenshot showing the network traffic (downloading plugin) and disk writes (writing the plugin .zip file) and CPU.

This is eating t2.large AWS credits within 2-3 hours. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there was an issue with the TC agent which was also running on the same server. The agent has been turned off but was attempting to upgrade components - such as `jetbrains.git` . I found `TeamCity Build Agent` in Windows Services and disabled it. This resolved the CPU issue.